# My construction phase for a timefold VRP is very slow. ~ about 11 seconds per step for a problem with around 1100 "customers" with 1/2 needing init,

Tags: timefold

My VRP has Time Windows, Truck capacities, multiple pickups per customers, and a second chained variable that tracks the volume of product based on the previous pickup.

Everything works well, (although I'm planning to move to enterprise to use Nearby selections), but the constrution phase is very slow.

I'm using this:

ALLOCATE_ENTITY_FROM_QUEUE
NONE
NONE

Which I thought would be the fastest option, and other variations I've tried like ALLOCATE_FROM_POOL, and FIRST_FIT were even slower.

So, am I correct in thinking it's slow? What sort of constraints or listeners might be slowing it down? I'm considering just manually initializing all the planning vaeiables.

I've tried various constructionHeuristic settings

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without actually seeing your code. Is it slow because of inefficient constraints? Is it slow because there are far too many options to try? Is it slow due to expensive variable listeners? And how slow is slow, exactly, in terms of score calculation speed? No way for me to know.

Comment: timefold-solver-benchmark is your friend, try setting it up to get a best score graph. See docs section on "benchmarker" to learn how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your score calculation speed of 11/sec is too slow. It should be more like 10 000 per second. There's no point in tweaking the Construction Heuristics or Local  Search to make up for that.

Run your dataset for 2 minutes multiple times. Each time, comment out one more of the constraints, to figure out which constraint is the bottleneck.

Comment: I will. But once I find the constraint(s) that are the bottleneck, is there a way to use them during local search but not in construction? Or should the constraints work for both?

Comment: You'll likely be able to rewrite them to work much faster.

Comment: I tried commenting out each rule.(which I should have known to try as the first step. for some reason I thought the constuction phase ignored most of the rules). I did find a slow oned and rewrote it. It's going about ten time as fast now, within the realm of being usable, but I did email timefold to arrange a call to discuss the enterprise version and  some paid support. It would be great to speed it up more, and even better to learn what I'm doing wrong in general.